# HTML PDF dynamical height

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have an HTML, which is displaying a lot of PDF files. They are arranged in a table, and the table scales dynamically.

For a while this format was working:

```css
.main .work {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main .work .media {
  width: 100%;
}

.main .work .caption {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0;
}

.main .work a:hover .caption {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%" height="100%">
        <div class="work">
          <a href="inner_004.html">
            <embed src="https://www.oic.qld.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0006/7755/other-sample-googleanalytics-report.pdf#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf" padding-bottom="1000pt">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="work_title">
                <h1>Report1</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="33%" height="100%">
        <div class="work">
          <a href="inner_005.html">
            <embed src="http://www.googleguide.com/print/adv_op_ref.pdf#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf" padding-bottom="1000pt">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="work_title">
                <h1>Report2</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="33%" height="100%">
        <div class="work">
          <a href="inner_006.html">
            <embed src="https://www.oic.qld.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0006/7755/other-sample-googleanalytics-report.pdf#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf" padding-bottom="1000pt">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="work_title">
                <h1>Report3</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="1%">
        <div class="work">
          <a href="MQBOVERALL.html">
            <img src="https://assets.mspcdn.net/t_c-desktop-normal,f_auto,q_auto,d_c:noimage.jpg/c/12200-67-3.jpg" class="media" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The HTML was working fine for a while, the PDFs were scaling with the table. I even have that Scaler image at the end of the table as a 4th cell, which makes sure that the cells should have a ration of 1:1.

I think in one of the recent updates in chrome made this happen.Now it's completely broken, and the PDFs have a fixed height. Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: The same goes when I try to insert an HTML instead of the PDF:

```html
<td width="33%" height="100%"> 
  <div class="work">
    <a href="inner_010.html">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/" width="200%" height="190%" style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);-webkit-transform-origin: top left;-moz-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5); -moz-transform-origin: top left;">
        &lt;p&gt;Your browser does not support iframes.&lt;/p&gt;
      </iframe>
      <div class="caption">
        <div class="work_title">
          <h1>Measurement and Analysis<br>Overview</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</td>
```

Edit2:

So basically a while ago this code resulted PDFs and HTML previews dinamically scaling with the other elements of the table. As you can seee there's that scaler image, which scales well if I change my window size in the live version. However the PDF and HTML previews' height remains a constant 150 for some reason. I want them to scale with the image, however only their with is scaling, not their height.

Comment: I am still not understanding your question .

Comment: can you elaborate more of this question.

Comment: Sore, sorry, I'm adding more to the question.

Comment: I am ready to help you but I am not able to understand your question that is a reason I request you.

Comment: Thank you in advance, see the end of my question please. I added an Edit2 section.

Comment: so if I am understand, then your question is that when you use pdf then the height may scaling well in table but when you use html it will not right?

Comment: Yeah, basically yes. I inserted PDFs into the cells of my table. My cells are scaling all right, however the PDF inside the cells keep the constant 150 pixel height.

Comment: I think it is my bad that still I am not understanding well your question and trying to give you an answer

Comment: I'll try again, sorry. So basically I have a table in my page, which scales if you enlarge the browser. It'll keep staying the same width as the browser. Inside it table there are pictures, PDFs and HTML previews. The pictures are scaling all right when I enlarge the browser window, both width and height. However the PDFs and the HTML previews only scale in widht, and they keep their height at a fixed 150pixel for some reason, although I haven't specified 150pixels, I specifies "100%" everywhere, which should mean they take the height if the cell in the table. But they don't change their heigh

Comment: Does your issue not solve yet?

Comment: Still no solution unfortunately

Comment: so will you stay connected with me in chat so I shall resolve your issue

Comment: I would be very thankful, if you would do that! Thank you!

Comment: sure I am ready  my friend

Comment: I insist to keep online because I am not getting this well that is a reason. so it will helpful to you if you come online I shall available after 2 hours.

Comment: I will do my best, my connection is not very good at live notifications, so I have about a 5 minute delay

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165159/discussion-between-dipak-chavda-and-caj69i).

Comment: Unfortunately my job place's connection blocks chat sites, thus I can't access it. I'll be at home in about 2-3 hours, but I don't want to make you stay awake all night just for this.
I'll create an online example for my code on a site, and send you the link tomorrow. Thank you once again very much for your dedication, it means a lot to me!